# MySQL - Result consisted of more than one row

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am a MySQL rookie and have been trying to create a stored procedure. The code below returns the error `Error Code: 1172. Result consisted of more than one row`. What am I doing wrong? (I'm using MySQL workbench)

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `season_private_league_user`(
IN user_id INT,
OUT league_name VARCHAR(25),
OUT host_user VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN

    DECLARE userteamid INT;
    DECLARE var_league_name VARCHAR(25);
    DECLARE var_host_user VARCHAR(30);

    # Retrieve user team from user_id
    SELECT CS_USER_TEAMS_ID INTO userteamid
    FROM classicseasonmodel_classicseasonuserteam
    WHERE user_id = user_id;

    #LEAGUE NAME
    SELECT classicseasonmodel_classicseasonprivateleague.private_league_name INTO var_league_name
    FROM   classicseasonmodel_classicseasonuserteamprivateleague
    INNER JOIN classicseasonmodel_classicseasonprivateleague
    ON classicseasonmodel_classicseasonuserteamprivateleague.private_league_id=classicseasonmodel_classicseasonprivateleague.CS_PRIVATE_LEAGUE_ID
    WHERE  user_team_id = userteamid;

    #HOST_USER
    SELECT classicseasonmodel_classicseasonprivateleague.host_user_id INTO var_host_user
    FROM   classicseasonmodel_classicseasonuserteamprivateleague
    INNER JOIN classicseasonmodel_classicseasonprivateleague
    ON classicseasonmodel_classicseasonuserteamprivateleague.private_league_id=classicseasonmodel_classicseasonprivateleague.CS_PRIVATE_LEAGUE_ID
    WHERE  user_team_id = userteamid;

    SET league_name = var_league_name;
    SET host_user = var_host_user;

END
```

`CALL season_private_league_user(2, @league_name, @host_user);
SELECT @league_name AS league_name;
SELECT @host_user AS host_user;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column name and parameter name are identical. Rename your input parameter and change the command to this:

```
SELECT CS_USER_TEAMS_ID INTO userteamid
FROM classicseasonmodel_classicseasonuserteam
WHERE user_id = @user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the SELECTs of you stored procedure that store the result in a variable returns more than one row, which returns in this error. This way you can only store single values in a variable, not multiple ones.

You can read about the SELECT...INTO statement [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html). The part that might be most interesting for you is:

> The selected values are assigned to the variables. The number of
>   variables must match the number of columns. The query should return a
>   single row. If the query returns no rows, a warning with error code
>   1329 occurs (No data), and the variable values remain unchanged. If
>   the query returns multiple rows, error 1172 occurs (Result consisted
>   of more than one row). If it is possible that the statement may
>   retrieve multiple rows, you can use LIMIT 1 to limit the result set to
>   a single row.